# I had a comment on an answer which was not a discussion, why was it removed?

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

I had a comment on the top rated answer by forest, and it was removed it appears.

I thought my comment was specific to that answer, and there was no discussion, at least on my side.  Thanks in advance.

[How to explain intravenous drug abuse to a 6-year-old?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/37177/explaining-intravenous-drug-abuse-to-a-small-child/37187?noredirect=1#comment77999_37187)

***EDIT***

This is roughly the text I had in the comment, I have a copy of it because I was asked to remove it from my answer, since comments on other answers should be in the comments section.  Presumably they won't be deleted if they are valuable?

(... something about kids making good decisions was in the original answer I was commenting on... )

> ...Which sadly makes me wonder if that is true why so many kids have
>   multiple cavities and why the most well known and most accepted story
>   of creation starts with 2 people eating a forbidden fruit which will
>   kill them...  ([btw, over 1/2 the world believes this story](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272933/idiom-for-doing-something-intentionally-despite-knowing-the-outcome-might-be-bad))
>
> Also, it is shown in human nature to willfully do things which we know
>   will harm us.  We have many saying that discern a variety of reasons
>   to intentionally do things we know will have negative consequences. 
>   Simply put, the biblical story of creation is acted out frequently in
>   our daily lives. One example is the [variety of answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272933/idiom-for-doing-something-intentionally-despite-knowing-the-outcome-might-be-bad) at English
>   Stack Exchange.

I think my comment is very relevant to the premise of the answer and should be something anyone looking at will consider.  I cannot understand why it was removed, especially considering comments are normally left in place, as you can see many existing comments are already.

Comment: Why are you linking to a comment to your own answer then? Was it [this comment](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/37177/explaining-intravenous-drug-abuse-to-a-small-child/37187?noredirect=1#comment77990_37178) by any chance? In general, comments are considered *seconf class citizens* and can get deleted anytime.

Comment: @AnneDaunted I don't know how to intentially link to a specific answer, sorry.  The Answer to the question was by forest, and I had a longer comment under his answer, followed by the link which is still up.  I appreciate the information on the rules about comments being deleted, but I'm interested in why my comment was deleted.  I'm assuming that the status quo is to have respect for comments and only delete them for valid reasons.

Comment: Considering you also posted an answer, could it be that your comment on forest's answer looks like an answer? If that's the case, then it might be correctly removed since [comments shouldn't be used as an alternative solution to the question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) either. However, without an exact comment, it's difficult to evaluate (until mods come)...

Comment: @AndrewT. that is a good idea, but I don't think so.  I'm adding a copy of my comment, which I have only because I originally had it in my answer and a Mod asked me to remove it from my answer because answers should not comment on other answers, that is what comments are for - lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! Thanks for asking it. (+1) Sorry I didn't see it before now. (Our notification system failed me.)

Here's the comment *in toto*:

> No offense intended but this advice, while logically sound, seems to fail in reality. What kid control's their sugar intake by free will? What drug addict never had a single person tell them drugs are bad? I agree that logically things should be as you present them, but pragmatically they just aren't. I think discretion is very important in what to discuss and how to discuss it. Also, poison candy is exactly what Adam and Eve fell for, and even if you don't believe in that, all humans continue to repeat that mistake – Adam Heeg

Please note @Rory Alsop's comment at the top of the comments:

> Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat.

Although I wouldn't classify your comment as an argument, I would classify it as a challenge to the user posting it, not a question asking for clarification or suggesting an improvement (though this may sound like semantics to some.) When someone disagrees with an answer, often the best approach is to post your own answer, which you did. It was only after you edited that part out of your answer that you left it under the the user's answer.

You could have included this aspect in your own answer, just not as a meta comment (a comment on someone else's post as an answer/part of an answer.) As I stated in my comment to you (now deleted, as it was no longer an issue), rebutting the answers (note the plural) of others in your answer is not really kosher.

The second issue is that once a conversation has been moved to chat, further comments are often deleted unless they really *are* asking for clarification or suggesting an improvement. I deleted your comment (among others) because of these two issues.

I believe it was laziness/misunderstanding that I didn't click through your link to realize your undeleted comment was related to the first one, and not a helpful addition to the user's answer.

This is my reasoning. Please (@Adam Heeg/everyone) feel free to down vote this answer if you think it's not helpful or useful. If you disagree with removing critical comments left after the comments have been moved to chat, that's a different issue, and should be addressed in a different meta post. On a Hot Network Question, we sometimes get in excess of 40 comments; many of them are simply chaff, some are disagreements with the answer, some are downright rude (and yet they get upvoted, sometimes highly!), etc. When they have been moved to chat, people are more than welcome to disagree in the chatroom created for that question/answer. When they are really doing what comments are supposed to be used for, I don't delete them.

<sub>N.B. This is much more common on a HNQ.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for spending the time to let me know how it went down, it is really encouraging that you care enough to explain it so well and not ignore my question (as some sites do).  ;)

Comment: @AdamHeeg - I can understand your confusion and I apologize for putting you in that situation. I can say with a fair amount of certainty that had it not been a HNQ and the comments moved to chat, your comment would have been left alone. So I did cause the awkward situation, and for that, again, I'm sorry.